# Is there any way to connect Openfire users and facebook chat users

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

Currently I am doing a Poker game similar to Zynga Poker. I have integrated XMPP for iOS into my project and it is working absolutely fine.

Now I am able to do following things.

**Authenticating users with Open fire account and Facebook account**.

**Getting the presence status of available users**

**Creating group chat rooms**

**registering new users to Openfire server**

Now what I want to do is to connect / send / receive messages between Openfire server users (ex:  user@server.com) to user@chat.facebook.com).

Is it possible in XMPP? I didn't find any ideas about this. If you have any idea please let me know.

As I have played Zynga Poker, when I logged in as a Facebook user some other users are playing with me who are not my friends.

When I examined XMPP user authentication there is authentication method for user with password, authenticate with facebook accesstoken, **authenticateAnonymously**.

The one which I think they are doing is they are authenticating anonymously. If you have idea about my situation please suggest your remarks.

One more thing I want is to send and receive invites from/to users.

Comment: Search on google Quickblox.com and download its sdk example

Comment: http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS

Comment: My client has given his server along with Openfire XMPP port and admin panel.